# How to debug windows service which fails in Init() method

Tags: debugging, windows-services, service

I have a windows service which fails in Init() method and throws some exception , so only way for me to check what the error is by looking at the event log. I want to debug the windows service, but the problem is that i can attach debugger only when service is rnning, in my case it fails in Init() method only. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can programatically attach the debugger as the first line in the function:

```
Debugger.Launch ();
```

after adding the using statement:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is to have a class with a `static void Main()` entry point, which I can then temporarily assign in the project properties. From there, I call the same startup functions that are called when the app is run as a service.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can get the dumps of the crash using DebugDiag or windbg.

is your service C++ or C#.

Also maybe it is just a first chance exception and not really a crash. Can you provide more info on the failure.