# Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error

Tags: c#

i have to create one wcf  windows service in "C#"...sometimes it displays this error 
"Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error" in my windows service exe...where this error happan i dont know..there is no stack traces.. anybodies give solution.thanks in advance..

Comment: Can't help without more details. When does the exception happen? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a C# question to me.

Answer (score 0):

can you reproduce the error consistently?  If so attach a debugger ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914296/how-to-debug-windows-service-which-fails-in-init-method/1914318#1914318) [or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629720/debug-windows-service/2629761#2629761)) to the service and follow the steps to reproduce the error, setting break points in the places where the error happens.

If not try adding some logging to your service to try and trackdown where the problem is happening and give you some where to focus your investigations when it does crash.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check through the Windows Event Viewer for further information on what this error may be.

Then I would be tempted to place try...catch blocks within your code in likely places where you may be triggering this error. The Event viewer may give you more detial as to what was called to trigger the error.

As you have written a service I would suggest that you look at logging faults like this within the Event Viewer rather than in a log file (although there's no harm in doing this for a fast test).